# Load Class, Generate Object of this class

Tags: java, class, dynamic, reflection, classcastexception

I'm a beginner at java Reflection/Dynamic Loading. I want to load a specific Class ( that implements an Interface ) from a jar-File. Further more i want to initialize an Object of this Class and cast it to my specific Interface.

I tried `.loadClass()`, `class.forName()` and if I cast `Myclass.newInstance` to my Interface I'll get a ClassCastException.

How could I program my plugin-Loader, so it loads my class in my jar and cast it to `myInterface`?

### Edit

My Server has the same Interface as my Plugins implement. Now I want my Plugins "loaded" and cast to my Interface so I could use them normally.

### Edit

Here is some sample Code of my try to get a rid of these errors :D

```
URL url = f.toURL();  
URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

Class<ModInterface> c = (Class<ModInterface>)cl.loadClass("com.myapp.mod");

Class<? extends ModInterface> sub = c.asSubclass(ModInterface.class);
Constructor<? extends ModInterface> con = sub.getConstructor();
ModInterface mi = con.newInstance();
```

another code sample what I've done:

```
               ClassLoader loader = PluginLoader.class.getClassLoader();
               URL url = new URL("jar:file:" + f.getAbsolutePath() + "!/");
               URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url }, loader);
               Class iInterfaceClass = Class.forName("com.myapp.mod", true, ucl);
               ModInterface mi = (ModInterface) iInterfaceClass.newInstance();
```

### Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.mod cannot be cast to myapp.ModInterface
```

After some help provided by you i've done the following:

```
URL url = f.toURI().toURL();
   URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
   ClassLoader loader = ModInterface.class.getClassLoader();
   ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls, loader);
   Class<?> loadedClass = Class.forName("com.myapp.mod", true, cl);
   Class<? extends ModInterface> pluginClass = loadedClass.asSubclass(ModInterface.class);
   ModInterface mi = pluginClass.newInstance();
```

Now i get this error -> java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.myapp.mod thrown at loadedClass.asSubclass(..);
The specific class is found, because if i change com.myapp.mod to whatever it throws a classnotfound execption. I've tried to use the ModInterface ClassLoader, but nothin changed. with(out) i'll get the same error.

Note://
I use 2 Projects. 1 for my Server App, the other for my Plugin that should be loaded. Both have the same Interface.

edit://

with this code i get an Object of type Object from my desired class, but it's not an instance of my ModInterface although my Class implements my ModInterface. If i try to cast my Object to my ModInterface a Error appears. Here is my short code:

```
Class c = clazzLoader.loadClass(element.getName().replaceAll(".class", "").replaceAll("/", "."));
Object instance = c.newInstance();
```

Comment: Care to post the code you have tried? Also, do you have a reason for using reflection? Having the compiler ensure type safety of your code is generally preferred, unless you have something that _must_ be deferred until runtime.

Comment: I failed a bit, i want to load a class from a Jar-file and this class implements an interface. The generated Object should be casted to this known Interface so i could use this normally in my plugin-loader.

And no i don't have Problems with posting my code, but i can't answer my topic within 8 hours, as it appears in Rules.

Comment: You don't need to _answer your topic_. Just edit your question and post the code.

Comment: code added, hope you could help me :)

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: ok sorry i just want to be specific as possible within my topic

Answer (score 1):

It seems you know the concrete names of the class that implements the interface and must be instantiated. In that case the following will work:

Consider the following interface

```
package test.api;
public interface Plugin {
    void service();
}
```

with the following implementation

```
package test.impl;
import test.api.Plugin;
public class PluginImpl implements Plugin {
    @Override
    public void service() {
        System.out.println(":-)");
    }
}
```

Then the following code snippet will do what you want (and prints out ":-)"):

```
Class<?> loadedClass = Class.forName("test.impl.PluginImpl");
Class<? extends Plugin> pluginClass = loadedClass.asSubclass(Plugin.class);
Plugin plugin = pluginClass.newInstance();
plugin.service();
```

You can also get the correct class reference by using an appropriate class loder (as you did in your code example).

Note, that `Class.forName` returns a `Class<?>`, which must be cast afterwards. This cast can better be done with `Class.asSubClass`. If the loaded class does not implement the interface, you will just get a `ClassCastException`.

However ... If you want to build up a simple plugin mechanism, you should consider using a [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), which requires your pluggable JARs to define a service configuration file. See the link for more explanation.

BTW: The class to be loaded in your code example looks more like a package name, so that it cannot be found. Maybe this is your problem?

Comment: this could be also my Problem. i got my file-handle with my absolute Path to my jar, i defined that in every plugin it has to be a path called com.myapp.mod. Mod is the class that implement my interface and which is recognized by my server. Now i try to load the class over my filehandle, i know that the class i ve to load is called com.myapp.mod.

Comment: My Path is right and my Class gets found but if i try to use .asSubClass(..) i get an Error. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems you want to dynamically load the `interface` say `A` , as well as the implementing `class` say `B`. You can do it via reflection as :

```
Class<?> bClass = Class.forName("packagename.B", true, loader);
Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("packagename.A", true, loader);
Object bObject = // create an instance of class B via Reflection
Object aObject = aClass.cast(bobject);
```

Remember, both the class definitions has to be loaded from a class loader that is a common parent for both. The only purpose the cast serves here to ascertain that indeed `B` is a subtype of `A`.

[Class#cast()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) :

> Casts an object to the class or interface represented by this Class object.

[Reflection tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html) will help you to know hoe to create instances reflectively.

Comment: i add this to the comments above, i actually have an interface that all of my plugins have to implement. My Server have also this Interface, i only want to load a class and cast it to my Interface.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my Problem myself. I've done a client lib that integrate my ModInterface. After that i added this .jar to my Projects, so both have the same Modinterface-Base. After this step ClassLoader.LoadClass is possible without any Casting-Exceptions.

Thanks for your help